# How to verify user input of (username and password) from .txt file? python

Tags: python-3.x, file, tkinter, verification

I am designing a login system and I'm stuck is writing the .txt file because I didn't understand how will python read it.

I tried to write in different format:
-usernamepassword
-username password
-username
 password
 and I always got the same output `"invalid username or password"`. I need to know if the problem is with the file or with the code?

```
class TeamLogin(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        def loginS():
              f1 = userS.get()
              p1 = passS.get()
              list_of_files = os.listdir()
              if f1 in list_of_files:
                  file1 = open(users, "r")
                  verify = file1.read().splitlines()
                  if p1 in verify:
                     controller.show_frame("Safetyteam")
              else:
                    L = tk.Label(self,text="invalid username or password", font=controller.title_font).pack()


        L1 = tk.Label(self, text="Safety Team Login", font=controller.title_font).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        L2 = tk.Label(self,text="Enter username and password", font=controller.title_font).pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=20)

        userS = StringVar()
        passS = StringVar()

        L3 = tk.Label(self,text="username", font=controller.title_font).pack()
        e1 = tk.Entry(self, textvariable=userS).pack()
        L4 = Label(self,text="password", font=controller.title_font).pack()
        e2 = tk.Entry(self,textvariable=passS,show="*").pack()
        b1 = tk.Button(self, text = "Login", command=loginS).pack()
        b2 = tk.Button(self, text = "Back", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Main")).pack()
```

Comment: It appears that you're trying to compare a username to a filename. Is that your intent?

Comment: no, I'm comparing the input to the username inside the file

Comment: Then that's part of your problem, because you're comparing the username to a filename: `f1 = userS.get() ... f1 in list_of_files`.

Comment: use `print(list_of_files)` to see what you have in variable. It is not text from file. To get text from file you would need at least `text_from_file = open("filename.txt").read()`